# How to create BRISK Feature Detection with Parameters on OpenCv Java 2.4.9

Tags: javacv, feature-detection, feature-extraction, brisk

I know there is constructor for BRISK in OpenCv C++ so that one can set up threshold,octave values but I can't find a similar thing on OpenCv Java. I know there is create() method  to create BRISK but cannot set up values such as threshold and octave on Java.

How can I achieve this on OpenCv Java 2.4.9, is it possible?